# add nsmutablearray as parameter in afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i am trying to send nsmutablearray as one parameter of dictionary e.g

```
NSMutableDictionary* dicUsers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dicUsers setValue:txtTitle.text forKey:@"task_title"];
[dicUsers setValue:txtVDetail.text forKey:@"task_detail"];
[dicUsers setValue:myArray forKey:@"assign_to"];    

AFHTTPClient *httpClient= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@",SERVER_PATH]]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient postPath:@"Task/addTask" parameters:dicUsers success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Print the response body in text

    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",dic);// NULL RESPONSE
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
}];
```

sending by post method but cant get the array so how i send the array as one parameter

Comment: It's not clear how you send it, you should more code.

Comment: i edit the code and add more code

Answer (score 0):

If you would have a look at the error of `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];` you probably would get your answer:

`responsObject` is not a NSData objects. It is either an NSArray or an NSDictionary, as it is already the serialised object.